# Is there a way to search for a missing endif?

Tags: php, errors

I have inherited a Wordpress site that I am moving to a new server. On the new server I am getting the following error:

> ParseError thrown syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE)

The site has thousands of files. Is there a quick way to identify which file has the offending 'endwhile' statement?

Wordpress 4.9.7
PHP 7.0.30

Comment: The error message should tell you the file and line number.

Comment: And the issue likely isn't a missing `endif`. The issue is that the `endwhile` was unexpected. This can mean you have an extra `endwhile` without a corresponding `while` or it could just mean that you have a missing `;` on a previous line. And I can guarantee you that the issue is not in any of WordPress' files, unless you've modified them. It's probably somewhere in your own code.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. The error does not show file or line number. Is there a way to force it to? I did narrow it down to the theme files.

Comment: Check your error log, it should be in there too. If you can't find it, enable [`WP_DEBUG_LOG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and check `wp-content/debug.log`.

Comment: Thanks again Jacob - I really appreciate your help. My error log is showing several deprecated functions in some 3rd party plugins, but nothing in the theme files. I suspect it's the theme files because if I switch themes the site works. I am going through the loops manually, but it's frustrating because they may start in one file, and end in another.